# Знаковый словарь

Tags: лексикография

Что такое знаковый словарь специалиста?

Answer (score 2):

Видимо, от сочетания ЭКСПЕРТНЫЕ ЗНАКИ - система обозначений, кот. пользуются эксперты.У каждого специалиста свои знаки.

Вот филателисты, например, на обороте исследованных марок в определенном месте, на цельных и целых вещах рядом или под знаком почт, оплаты ставится Э. з. в виде оттиска. На нем может быть указана фамилия (иногда сокращенная) или факсимиле эксперта.